# Save screenshot to Dropbox on PC having keyboard without PrintScreen button on Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, dropbox, screenshot

I have an HTPC where I watch tutorials on youtube or wherever, but the cheap BT keyboard I have for this doesn't sport a PS button.

I want to take screenshots on this machine to my Dropbox so I can access on other machines

I checked out most of the Chrome addons which promised to do this, they were all useless for this.

The only slightly-useful one I found was SS-Extension but its clunky and manual to drop DB.

Is there any way I can do this just a right-click - save to DB?

Comment: [How do I ask a question that may require recommending a web app?](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3705/354)

Answer (score 1):

you can try **CloudShot** - **[install](http://cloudshot.com/downloads/release/CloudShotSetup.exe) / [portable](http://cloudshot.com/downloads/portable/CloudShot.zip)** - where you are allowed to assign a hotkey for your screenshot

[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: terrific ! Just what the Dr. ordered :)

Comment: Please stop answering off-topic questions.  Flag them to be closed instead.

Comment: @jonsca I am pretty sure that my history says that I flag a lot... and up to date I answered 2-3  such questions out of ~80... this one wasnt marked as offtopic at that time and cant rly predict if there isnt "web-app" answer for it... I just seen it and answered it on the fly with most suitable and effective answer to my knowledge. delete it if you need so.

Comment: @user0 The question specifically was asking for a Chrome extension or an application.  It just seemed to me that lately you had been squeezing in a few answers when the questions were already on their way to being closed.  While there's absolutely nothing wrong with trying to be helpful, answering just sets a bad precedent because people will start posting off-topic questions in the hope that they get answered anyway before they are closed.

Comment: @jonsca Didn't even know a sub-domain like this existed until now....that's cool, just when I thought SE might be getting too off-topic about being off-topic :) when did they create it ? Is there a place I can see a list of all sub-domains of SE ?

Comment: @killjoy Which "sub-domain" are you asking about?  Our site?  This one was started around 7 years ago already.  It was one of the very first to graduate from the Area 51 process (http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/57/web-applications)  The page https://stackexchange.com/sites is a list of all the sites on SE.  Hope you find some great ones!

Comment: Thanks @jonsca ! Appreciate you takin the time to respond.